# Reported to Direct speech conversion

Tags: speech

This is one of the questions in an exam. According to the official answer key, correct answer is (B). But I found that the most correct answer could be (A). Can any one please point out the right answer with justification?

> DIRECTIONS: The following sentences are given in Direct speech.
>   Change these sentences into correct reported speech:
>
> Q. He said to him, “ Is not your name Ram”.
>
> > (A)  He asked him if his
> >     name was Ram.
> >
> > (B)  He inquired whether his name was not Ram.
> >
> > (C)  He said to him if his name was not Ram.
> >
> > (D)  He narrated him if name was
> >     not Ram

Comment: B is correct. Technically, the question (inquiry) was, "Is **not** your name Ram?" To which the expected answer is "Yes" *if* his name *is* Ram. The question was *not* "Is your name Ram?" which is a bit different. The strict interpretation is that A in not correct; that was not the question. In real life, however, there is not as *great* a difference between the two: they both seek to establish the person's name.

Comment: @medica: The expected answer _if_ his name is Ram would be _no_, if Ram happens to be a programmer. After all, _no_ indicates that the proposed statement (your name is not Ram) is _incorrect_. "Normal"  people tend to answer the opposite of the logical answer, though, which goes to show that asking negative questions is a bad idea in general.

Comment: I edited the directions so that it correctly poses the test item as a conversion from direct to reported speech, rather than the way it was first given, which was reported to direct. And, if the source is the postal assistant exam of India, then the correction is true to the source.

Comment: It depends on whether "Is not your name Ram?" is an artifact of Indian-English, with its idiosyncratic inversion of word order and stilted avoidance of contractions. It is formal and declamatory, such speech as might be heard in court. A Western speaker of English might say "Isn't your name Ram?" ("Is your name not Ram?") if there was some doubt about the matter, but if he merely desired information he would say "Is your name Ram?" [A] asks in the latter way; [B] asks in the former. What Indians may mean by inserting the negative is another question.

Comment: @Robusto For the purposes of the question lets say you have no idea what 'type' of English was used. It's simply a question posed in writing with no other clues as to any originating dialect or whatever. _Is not your name Robusto?_, which of the conversions is correct. Might be better if edited to _Is not your name John?_ .

Comment: @Frank: In most cases, I would probably say that *A* is the most common, and probably the most natural as well—unless the questioner means to cross-examine someone to ferret out misinformation or deceit.

Comment: The question is not correct English; _is not_ at the beginning of a yes/no question is always contracted to _isn't_, even in writing. Consequently, nothing can be concluded about the answers, since the exam was constructed by a non-English speaker, and who knows **what** rules they're following?

Comment: @jwpat7: Right on, thanks. Got it in time to correct it.

Comment: @JohnLawler So are you saying that the reported speech should be written as _Isn't your name Ram/John?_ and also that no native English speakers would use _Is not your name Ram/John?_

Comment: I would be surprised if a native American English speaker asked _Is not your name John?_ as a question. I'd suspect I was being made sport of, or that the speaker was not a native English speaker. And, yes, it should be written that way, too, since the point of writing is to convey information instead of to show off one's education.

Comment: @JohnLawler Would you say the same of a native British English speaker, or someone who spoke British English?

Comment: @JohnLawler: I'm surprised that you would be so prescriptive in this case. There is no law against using "Is not . . . " for emphasis. Granted it sounds wrong, and would certainly be stilted, possibly shading toward hyper-correction, but I could certainly imagine it being used, as I said, in a court of law as a direct rebuttal of some kind. Used by an inexpert practitioner, however, it could easily sound "incorrect."

Comment: I find it strange that you think me prescriptive, @Robusto. There's no law against any grammar usage; I merely point out that contraction is almost universal in this case, and therefore variation from the expected structure is highly marked and may be significant. Certainly it is noticed, and may be subject to further interpretation; we pay attention to things that surprise us, after all. And, Frank, any British accent (the posh one is RP, of course) would unmark the construction in speech.

Comment: @JohnLawler "almost universal in this case, and therefore variation from the expected structure is highly marked and may be significant" and that is exactly why I put on a bounty on this question; not to have it cast aside as a 'non-native error'. It is/was common in BrE; J. Bentham uses it when supporting 'suggestive interrogation' and as noted in another answer Shakespeare and the Biblical texts seemed keen on it. No doubt I could find myriad references in BrE, perhaps less so in AmE.

Comment: @Frank: You don't give the source of the exam, so as far as can be determined in print by a native speaker, the exam question, and possibly the exam, was constructed by a speaker of an unusual  dialect or sociolect of English (perhaps British Legal English or Indian English or Chinese English), or for testing speakers of an unusual dialect or sociolect. Or perhaps it's self-published by a self-proclaimed expert. One can hardly tell without more evidence; just like the sentence itself.

Comment: @JohnLawler I don't know the origin of the question either, so I can be of no help there I'm afraid. Perhaps you would like to wrap up your comments into an answer, stating that the question should be in the written form of _Isn't your name Ram?_ and whether A or B is the correct conversion. It may be useful for a future user asking a similar question.

Answer (score 7):

The task is to choose the answer that best gives the correct reported speech for the direct speech given. The direct speech question stem is:

Q. He said to him, “ Is not your name Ram”.

Choice (A) **WOULD** be the best choice **IF** it included *not*, as in,

He asked him if his name was *not* Ram.

However, the (A) choice was written without the *not*, as:

(A) He asked him if his name was Ram.

Even though the (B) choice has the awkward wording of "*He inquired whether* his name was not Ram," because it includes *not* in the sentence, it more closely mirrors the stem question.

Therefore, the (B) choice is the best available rendering of the question stem:

(B) He inquired whether his name was not Ram.

As is often the case with multiple choice questions, a perfectly satisfying choice may not be given, and the task is to choose the **best** choice from those that are given.

Answer (score 4):

In this instance, you do not have enough contextual information to determine the *effective* meaning of the question, so you have to rely on the literal meaning, which is reflected best in (B).

What the question is *effectively* asking can vary significantly. In the famous Monty Python sketch, "Is your name not Bruce?" is *effectively* a statement of incredulity (and poor Michael Baldwin is assigned the name Bruce, like everyone else in the Philosophy Department, to "cut down on the confusion"). More commonly, perhaps, in the real world, one would ask such a question when there is some doubt as to the name of the respondent (in the case of mistaken identity or an incorrect introduction). In that case, the question is often asked after it becomes apparent to the asker that there is a problem — the person being addressed is exhibiting signs of confusion or irritation — and the expected answer is "no" (or "yes, but how did you know that?", or perhaps "yes, but merely knowing my name doesn't automatically grant you the right to speak to me. Who let you in here? Security!!!").
In myths and heroic tales — including family mythologies — names often have more meaning than simply being a signifier for a signified person, and the question may be serving as a notification or reminder of some power or quality the respondent should possess and isn't using. In that case, the actual question is rhetorical.

Context means a lot in language, and you cannot make assumptions about the effective meaning of a single sentence excerpted from its context.

Answer (score 2):

One writer said the original quotation was ungrammatical. I'm guessing from the name in the sentence (and the user name of the OP) that this question might not originate in the United States or Great Britain. I live in a part of the U.S. now where I don't meet many people whose families come from India, so I can't easily confirm what I think is the most likely explanation: that *Is not your name Ram* might be acceptable for *many* English-speakers.  (Actually, I just remembered there's a student where I work now who comes from Gujarat; perhaps I can ask her in the next few days, not that a *no* would prove anything.)

There are several ways I might interpret the original question. It might be a rhetorical question:  The speaker already knows that the person's name is, indeed, Ram.

> — But Murali! I cannot break down the door!
>
> — Come now. Is not your name Ram?

(Sorry, that was bad.)

It might not be that strong, though:  Perhaps the speaker is only *fairly* sure that the person's name is Ram and doesn't mind being direct.  Maybe Ram works in a restaurant with a lot of other people; maybe the manager doesn't know everyone.  She says, "Isn't your name Ram? Yeah? Go help Jim over there with those boxes." (From here on, I'll assume *Is not your name* and *Isn't your name* are the same question.)

I'll put it this way:  Let's say I'm a tutor meeting Ram for the first time. We're meeting at the library.  I see someone who looks like he's waiting; he has a book for the subject we're covering.  (Maybe even we're in the southern U.S., and he's the only Indian guy in the place.)  I would *not* walk up to him and ask, "Isn't your name Ram?"  It's too direct. I would ask, "Is your name Ram?"

Of course, the utterance itself *Is your name Ram?* suggests that the speaker may have some idea about the answer. (The speaker may not, of course, but in general, there's going to be a reason for asking the question.) But it does not convey that idea nearly as strongly as the form in question. All things being equal, it's the most neutral form of the question.

So we have to pick one of the choices.

Option (D), *He narrated him if name was not Ram*, doesn't work because *narrate* is not, as far as I'm aware, a ditransitive verb. That is, it doesn't take two objects — as, for example, *give* does: *I gave her the book*.

Option (D) also has a problem shared by option (C), *He said to him if his name was not Ram*: Neither *narrate* nor *say* can take an adverbial clause as a complement. This is because they are both transitive verbs and therefore need a direct object — i.e., a noun.  For example,

> He said who we was looking for.
>
> He narrated what happened next.

(The *to him* in (C) sounds stilted to my ears, but I'm not sure I can say with conviction that it's wrong in American English.  I think I'd say, "He told him, etc.")

So it's down to (A), *He asked him if his name was Ram*, and (B), *He inquired whether his name was not Ram*.  (B) better preserves the nuances of the original question, whereas (A) converts it to the neutral form.  In (B), the writer merely reports what was said, letting the reader decide what the speaker meant — or, indeed, leaving the reader as clueless about the speaker's intentions as the writer himself may be. If we're looking at the question literally, (A) changes what was said.

As for the verb: Is *inquire* better than *ask*? It depends on the context. Again, *inquire* sounds a bit stiff to me. But I don't know what context this speech is being reported in; the writer may say to himself (hey, there's a *say* + indirect object thing!) that *ask* is too informal.

And finally:  *if* or *whether*?  There's a school of thought that says if it's a yes-no question, go with *whether*.  (And again, the extra syllable might suggest less, uh, levity.)

Comment: I've made an edit to change _Ram_ to _John_ to remove any 'non-native' bias that may encourage (but it's not been reviewed yet). **Is not the review team sleeping?**

Comment: @Frank I understand. I think you should leave it, though. In one sense, knowing the provenance of the question is necessary: I can say what the possible answers mean to me as an American; more importantly, though, I can posit which questions *lead* me to those interpretations, questions that Vikram can consider himself to better convince himself that (B) is, as the test-writers assure us, the correct answer. (Hopefully it is!) ...

Comment: @Frank Put it this way: Let's say someone is gonna get hung up on the name and say, *Well, that's not English*, when in fact it's simply not *their* English (yeah, I'm using a singular *they*). If, by changing the question, you hope to encourage that person to respond, I think you're just gonna get some other close-minded response: *Look, these're the rules.*

Comment: _Demz da rulez_ without showing the rules is just _Deez iz my rulez_. I hope changing _Ram_ to _John_ might stop _This is a non-native speaker and therefore wrong_ because I see nothing wrong with _Is not your name John?_, I'm just not sure that B is the right conversion.

Comment: Bounty in part for getting down with the '... could be A or could be B depending on ...' and also for the astonishing prediction of the opening of 'da boox of rulez'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "inquired" in reported speech is considered as **formal**. Therefore if there was an answer choice of "He inquired whether his name was Ram" like choice A but with 'inquired' that would be okay too. So in short it is like you said an exam paper that's why 'inquired', otherwise in spoken English choice A would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Only (B) expresses *doubt*, as does the question stem, if it is not a rhetorical question. (A) expresses *ignorance*, which is different. (C) and (D) are simply grammatically incorrect, and including ungrammatical answers in a multiple choice exercise is not a good idea.

Apart from that, I find the equation of 'reported speech' with 'indirect speech', as implied in the question title, confusing, even though it is correct usage. **Both 'direct speech' and 'indirect speech' are forms of 'reported speech'!** In order to be perfectly clear, one should say 'direct reported speech' and 'indirect reported speech' or 'direct speech' and 'indirect speech'.

The *Longman Dictionary of Contemprary English* defines 'direct speech' as

> speech **reported** using the actual words spoken as in " 'I don't want to go,' said Julie."

(My bold characters.)